# How to get id from last button and remove it in React using react-id-generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mern

So in `React` I made a button that every time you click it it generates a new button with a unique id using `react-id-generator`.

Now I want to get the id from the last button in the list and every time I click a remove button it should remove the last button generated.

Here is what have I done so far and i tried to remove the last button but it removes all the buttons:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import styles from '../styles/loginsignup.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import nextId from "react-id-generator";
export default class AccomodationInfo extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            accomcate: null,
            addroom: [''],
            isLoading: true,
        }
      }
  handleClick = event => {
        const htmlId = nextId("Room")
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({ addroom: [...this.state.addroom, htmlId] })
        }

    handleRemove = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({ addroom: [...""] })
    }



    render() {
        const{accomcate,  isLoading}  = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remove</button>
                <div>
                {this.state.addroom.map((addroom) => (
                <div>
                  <button id={addroom}>{addroom}</button>
                </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>



        )


    }


}
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
handleRemove = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(this.state.addroom[-1])
  this.setState(state => state.addroom.pop())
}
```

This will remove the last item in the list.
The reason you can use `pop()` on the state is by passing `setState` a function instead of an object. The function is passed the previous state as an argument which can be modified, and it replaces the immutable state object.

**Edit:** I noticed you also wanted the removed button's id, so I updated the code example above to log the id of the removed button.